# Build sqlite3 for windown 10 iot

Tags: node.js, sqlite, windows-10-iot-core

I try to build webserver on Windown 10 iot with Rasperry pi2 using Nodejs.

And i use sqlite as a database.

I try to import sqlite3 to Nodejs project by using this command:

```
npm install sqlite3 --build-from-source --target_arch=arm --target_platform=win32
```

Everything is ok.
But when i try to deploy it on Rasperry Pi 2. Server is auto stop working when i try to create database.

```
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database(':memory:');

db.serialize(function() {
  db.run("CREATE TABLE lorem (info TEXT)");

  var stmt = db.prepare("INSERT INTO lorem VALUES (?)");
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      stmt.run("Ipsum " + i);
  }
  stmt.finalize();

  db.each("SELECT rowid AS id, info FROM lorem", function(err, row) {
      console.log(row.id + ": " + row.info);
  });
});

db.close();
```

Error : The program '[2084] backgroundTaskHost.exe' has exited with code 1 (0x1).

Error log:

```
Error: The specified module could not be found.
\\?\C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\Packages\NodejsWebServer3_4hnzkqmdxyz32\LocalState\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v47-win32-arm\node_sqlite3.node
   at Module._extensions[.node] (module.js:450:3)
   at Module.prototype.load (module.js:356:3)
   at Module._load (module.js:311:5)
   at Module.prototype.require (module.js:366:3)
   at require (module.js:385:5)
   at Anonymous function (C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\Packages\NodejsWebServer3_4hnzkqmdxyz32\LocalState\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\sqlite3.js:4:1)
   at Module.prototype._compile (module.js:425:3)
   at Module._extensions[.js] (module.js:432:3)
   at Module.prototype.load (module.js:356:3)
   at Module._load (module.js:311:5)
```

Anybody know how to solve it.
Thanks

Comment: Add some error logging code to see what is actually going wrong

Comment: I have been edited post with error log message. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have the same issue, did you get anywhere? I determined that the module that gets deploy is the wrong architecture `node-v48-win32-x64` is actually getting installed.